# c++ Implicit copy of *this with std::list

Tags: c++, list, oop, reference, std

For a project, I have a list of objects, (in my example code, a Garden). Each Garden contains a single Plant, which has a reference to the Garden it's in. This works perfectly when making a single Garden, but when I create a std::list of Garden objects, suddenly a copy is created *somewhere* I don't know, and I have no idea how to fix it. The objects are as following:

```
struct Garden; //Forward declaration
struct Plant {
    Plant(Garden & myGarden) : theGarden(myGarden) { }; //Constructor
    Garden & theGarden; //reference to garden this Plant is in
};
struct Garden {
    Garden(int size) :  thePlant(*this), size(size) { }; //Constructor
    Plant thePlant; //Plant contained in this Garden
    int size;       //Size of this garden
};
```

So far so good. Now, I can create a Garden stand-alone, or put one in a list. The expected behaviour is that if I change the 'size' variable, it gets changed everywhere, also in `theGarden`. However, in a list, it only gets changed in the 'original' `Garden`, not in the reference `theGarden`

```
int main() {
    //Works
    Garden oneGarden(1);
    std::cout << "Expected: 1 1, result: "
            << oneGarden.size << " "
            << oneGarden.thePlant.theGarden.size << std::endl;
    oneGarden.size = 2;
    std::cout << "Expected: 2 2, result: "
            << oneGarden.size << " "
            << oneGarden.thePlant.theGarden.size << std::endl;

    //Does not work!
    std::list<Garden> gardenList;
    gardenList.push_back(Garden(1));
    std::cout << "Expected: 1 1, result: "
            << gardenList.front().size << " "
            << gardenList.front().thePlant.theGarden.size << std::endl;

    gardenList.front().size = 2;
    std::cout << "Expected: 2 2, result: "
                << gardenList.front().size << " "
                << gardenList.front().thePlant.theGarden.size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The final output is as following:

```
Expected: 1 1, result: 1 1
Expected: 2 2, result: 2 2
Expected: 1 1, result: 1 1
Expected: 2 2, result: 2 1
```

Comment: When gardens get copied, their plants will always refer to the original garden. That is how references work. They cannot be made to point to something else.

Comment: Given " suddenly a copy is created somewhere I don't know," is the question really where is the copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard containers *own* the elements they contain. That means copies are made of each element when you insert them.

When your `Garden` is copied, the default copy constructor is used and, in turn, the `Plant` member is also default-copied. However, this means the new `Plant` contains a reference to the *old* `Garden`.

In this case, that old `Garden` was the temporary in `gardenList.push_back(Garden(1))` so not only is it not the correct `Garden`, but it's a `Garden` that doesn't even exist any more. In short, you are reading the size through a dangling reference (which has undefined behaviour) and getting [un?]fortunate enough to see the old value behind it.

You should write a copy constructor for `Garden` that copies its `Plant` in every way *except* the new `Plant` should have a reference to the new `Garden`, instead of just copying the old reference.

The copy and the entire issue that stems from it can actually be avoided using new C++11 features:

```
gardenList.emplace_back(1);
```

Now, [the `Garden` in the list is created in-place](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back), and no copy will be performed.

However, you should *still* fix the underlying design problem with `Garden`, even if you work around the problem in this way.

Comment: +1 for the [un?]fortune remark... the most horrible thing in debugging is when something does work when it shouldn't. :)

Comment: Do I also need to override the `operator=()`?

Comment: I would have to add something: He initializes Plant with not completely constructed Garden which is dangerous. I suppose that your compiler gives you a warning about this reference member. He should consider writing copy/move constructors/operators as well as changing reference to pointer. unique_ptr can be handy here.

Comment: @Zorgiev I was worried about this too, but most sources consider this safe if done carefully; compiler finds this fine too, there's not even a 'note'. I find 'changing reference to pointer' a bit silly, as these are NOT the same at all, and in this case a reference is chosen for good reasons (which don't show in this example).

Comment: @Zorgiev: It's a potential source of errors, yes, though it's not illegal in this form. I don't think introducing pointers makes any sense here.

Comment: @sanchises: You would, yes, but depending on what `Plant` _actually_ does I think you should leave the `operator=` as it is, i.e. unavailable (because references cannot be rebound).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is indeed only used in this form, i.e., a single Plant in each Garden, so I'll leave the = operator as is. If I were to implement it anyway, should the = operator be otherwise the same as the copy constructor?

Comment: @sanchises: Again hard to say but yes it'll be similar